# C# Spline Interpolation for interpolating a key between array of points

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, interpolation, spline

I need an interpolation function for interpolating a point:

```
var times = new List<double>();
var offsets = new List<double>();
..
..
..//I fill times and offsets arrays with some points
..
var newTime= splineInterpolate(cursorOffset, offsets.ToArray(), times.ToArray())
```

Comment: I suggest using *Lagrange* interpolation for the closest 4 (in case of the most common cubic spline) points

Comment: I think stack overflow is not a *search a code snippet for me* site. Do you have a specific problem with your own implementation?

Comment: @adirano: I do agree with you... That's why I delete my answer... We should spend some efforts before throwing a question

Comment: @GoodLuck I know stackoverflow is not good for code snippets, but honestly I tried a couple of interpolation snippets which had erros, guessed people like you can help me :) So please share your answer. Thanks

Comment: :) I think eviltak answer is good enough!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of interpolation you want. If you don't want the interpolation function to pass through the control points, you can use a [Bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) (you can choose the order of the curve).

If you want the curve to pass through the control points, a popular choice is a [cubic Hermite spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline). There are many types of hermite splines like cardinal and catmull-rom splines (which are C1 and C2 continuous).

If you just do a simple Google search, you will come across thousands of results for splines with their implementation in C# provided.